# Pushing tags with git rejected as non-fast-forwarding

Tags: git

Git pull works doesn't show any updates:

```
sh-3.2$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

When I do a git push I get an error:

```
sh-3.2$ git push --tags
To user@example.com:some/git/repo
 ! [rejected]        DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE -> DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'user@example.com:some/git/repo'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

Rebasing gives the same:

```
sh-3.2$ git pull --rebase
Current branch devel is up to date.
```

The DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE tag is used on my daily automated build scripts, everytime I need to deploy some new stuff with those scripts I move that tag with:

```
git tag -f DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE
```

So, why can't I push my tag back?

I get this error every now and then for other tags which I don't move also.

Comment: dont use a tag if it's supposed to change. that's what branches are for. tags are supposed to be immutable

Comment: @NevikRehnel That design works very well for production deployments (were the tag won't change), but perhaps it is not ideal for a daily build. Still, I do get the same issues with the tags I don't move.

Comment: Git is very flexible and you can probably make it work, but you can expect it to work flawlessly when you're trying to shove the square peg into the round hole ;)

Comment: Incidentally, why do you even need such a daily-changing tag? If you just want to build&deploy whatever is current at the end of the day, just deploy `master` (or another branch). Daily builds are typically not tagged at all, you just take the latest version from the repo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you want to move the tag. Tags are designed to mark a specific state of your project, like release 1.0. This shouldn't be changed on daily basis. If you want to change (move) a tag anyway, you can do it using the -f (force) switch twice:

```
git tag -f TAG_I_MOVE
git push --tags -f
```

In your case I would use branches to mark the "developer bleeding edge"

```
git branch -f DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE HEAD
git push --tags
```

Here no "-f" switch for push needed, as long as you move your DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE branch forward within the same history path.

Comment: I agree, use branches for this kind of situation. They are internally not very different but have a completely different meaning. And moving tags is definitely not a recommend action (hence the `--force` switch you need when *updating* one)

Comment: Yeah, that works. I'll look into updating my build scripts, it just seemed easy to use the same script/logic to deploy to production and devel (script just asks for a tag to deploy), but the confusion caused by this side effect is not worth it.

Comment: @CleberGoncalves It shouldn’t change anything for deployment. A branch is a commit ref just like a tag is. So something like `git checkout DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE` will work just the same if `DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE` is a branch.

Comment: About the `git branch -f` - while this will work, it's not generally a good idea to use. If you only move the branch forward as usual, there's no need for it; you can just commit or merge into it. You really only need `git branch -f`  if you do *not* move the branch forward - in which case you you'll have to `push -f`, with all the problems this causes.

Comment: @sleske Agree with you. But how would you move DEVEL_BLEEDINGEDGE without checking out it?

Comment: @BorisBrodski: Yes, you'd need to check out the branch to commit/merge into it (at least I don't know another way apart from `branch -f`).